# How to add a time interval between Javascript animate API(the animation) and the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

#Javascript's official animation engine

i know this might sound dumb but i cant find any documentation for the animate API (not on youtube, not on google, not on stack overflow), so here is the relevant code

```js
if(secondary[0].style.display == "inline-block"){
    for(let i=0;i<secondary.length;i++){
        secondary[i].animate([
            {transform:"scale(1)",offset:0},
            {transform:"scale(0.7)",offset:0.3},
            {transform:"scale(0.3)",offset:0.7},
            {transform:"scale(0)",offset:1}
        ],{
            origin:'top',
            duration:2000,
            easing:"ease-in-out",
            fill:"forwards"
        })
    };
}
```

My issue is that if i add extra code the animation doesn't happen because the extra code executes immediately, and as i mentioned i cant find any information on the animate API, so i would like to know how to make my animation finish first and then execute the rest of the code.
(in case you are wondering i just want to make the display of the divs none after the animation)

```js
if(secondary[0].style.display == "inline-block"){
    for(let i=0;i<secondary.length;i++){
        secondary[i].animate([
            {transform:"scale(1)",offset:0},
            {transform:"scale(0.7)",offset:0.3},
            {transform:"scale(0.3)",offset:0.7},
            {transform:"scale(0)",offset:1}
        ],{
            origin:'top',
            duration:2000,
            easing:"ease-in-out",
            fill:"forwards"
        })
    };
    for(let i=0;i<secondary.length;i++){    //this code doesn't allow the animation to finish
         secondary[i].style.display = "none";
    }         
}
```

**Thanks in advance for your help**.

*and sorry if my question is trivial, i just couldn't find any documentation*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has onFinish handler. Please try this code snippet.

```
var anim = secondary[i].animate([
                    {transform:"scale(1)",offset:0},
                    {transform:"scale(0.7)",offset:0.3},
                    {transform:"scale(0.3)",offset:0.7},
                    {transform:"scale(0)",offset:1}
                ],{
                    origin:'top',
                    duration:2000,
                    easing:"ease-in-out",
                    fill:"forwards"
                });
anim.onfinish = function() {
  secondary[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Damn man you were really fast , it almost worked but your idea saved me(i literally wasted 3 hours on that :( ) , the only modification i made was just adding the a for loop but you are a life saver, thank you! And sorry if there was a better way to reply to you , if there is one i couldn't find it.

Comment: Great. I am happy it helped. :)

Comment: Do you know by any chance if there is any documentation for this API( i am not certain if it is an API), or if there is a reason why it lacks documentation? Again thanks in advance! Yes the problem is fully solved.

Comment: Of course they have api documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish

Comment: Damn i was on that site i just didn't figure out it was about that.... thanks again man.